# Problem resolving correct lib with maven: version managed from

Tags: maven

I am using Google Guava in my project.

I am explicitly specifying this version of a lib in one of downstream libraries:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I use my lib in the project, it brings the wrong version of Guava:

```
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:28.2-android:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
```

I ran maven `dependency:tree` in verbose mode and I see:

```
[DEBUG]       com.google.guava:guava:jar:28.2-android:compile (version managed from 19.0)
[DEBUG]          com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]          com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[DEBUG]          com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[DEBUG]          org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:jar:2.5.5:compile
[DEBUG]          com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.3.4:compile
```

What does `version managed from` mean? I do not have anywhere in my project version `28.2-android`. How is it resolving to it?

Comment: Something else is pulling in Guava then.

Comment: How do I detect that in maven? The dependency tree does not show it.

Comment: Maven deps are exhaustive AFAIK; if the tree doesn't show the transitive dependency when run on the "top level" project I'm not sure what to tell you--it should.

Answer (score 0):

The expression "version managed from" means that the version number was set in `<dependencyManagement>`.

This is often done in parent POMs. It can be specified directly, or also by a so-called BOM that is loaded with `<scope>import</scope>`.

Comment: Do you think it could be set by one of the Spring libs?

Comment: I would have a look at your parent POM and see if you find it.

Comment: Nope, it is not there, but thanks for your help!

Comment: It must be somewhere in the parent POM or its parent POM. It may be an imported BOM.

Comment: How do I find the "offending" dependency? I was searching for the version of that jar in my entire local maven repo and there were no matches.

Comment: You go to the `<dependencyManagement>` section of your parent POM. If it does not contain the entry, look for all entries with `<scope>import</scope>`. Open them and look for the dependency. If not successful go to the parent POM of your parent POM and repeat the procedure.